# I am having trouble using the addition formula to derive the identity from this problems

Tags: calculus

Use the addition formula to derive the identity:
$$\cos(x - \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin x$$

Comment: Do you mean $\cos{((\pi/2)-x)} = \sin{x}$?

Comment: Once you have corrected the statement of the problem, can you write out what happens when you use the addition formula for the cosine function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you mean $$\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)=\sin x\;.$$ The addition formula for the cosine is $$\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y\;.$$ Set $y=-\frac{\pi}2$, and it becomes

$$\begin{align*}
\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)&=\cos\left(x+\left(-\frac{\pi}2\right)\right)\\\\
&=\cos x\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}2\right)-\sin x\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}2\right)\\\\
&=\cos x\cdot0-\sin x\cdot(-1)\\\\
&=\sin x\;,
\end{align*}$$

because $\cos\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2\right)=0$ and $\sin\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2\right)=-1$.